# MPI cartesian grid : cumulate a scalar value through the procs of a given axis of the grid

Tags: mpi, cartesian-coordinates

I have an **MPI** question about using a **cartesian grid** of processors which represents a spatial domain decomposition (a cubic geometrical domain split into several smaller cubes...).
I have many possible communicators to address the procs, as for example a comm along each of the 3 axes I,J,K, or along a plane IK,JK,IJ, etc..).
**I need to cumulate a scalar value (SCAL) through the procs which belong to a given axis** (let's say the K axis, defined by I=J=0).
The origin proc 0-0-0 has a given value for SCAL (say SCAL000)
I want to update the 'following' proc (0-0-1) by doing SCAL = SCAL + SCAL000, and I want to **propagate** this along the axis. At the end, the last proc of the axis should have the total sum of SCAL along the axis. Please, do you see a way to do this with MPI ? I have tried many things (with MPI_SENDRECV, but unsuccessfully...). Thank you in any case.

Comment: I think you are probably looking for `mpi_reduce` or one of its relatives.  Or possibly `mpi_scan`.

Comment: `MPI_Cart_create` -> `MPI_Cart_sub` -> `MPI_Reduce`

Answer (score 0):

I give some precision on my question (and an answer): 
I have a 3D domain which is split into a cartesian grid of subdomains with MPI. Each sub-domain knows its size (physical size in meters) but doesn't know it's absolute position relatively to a given absolute origin, and this is what I needed.
My solution (probably classical) consists in a cycling shift in the 3 directions (only X direction is shown hereafter) and make a MPI_SENDRECV.
In the following, I suppose I know:
 - "NEIGHBORS": array which gives the process number of the 6 direct neighbors of the current process.
-  ALRNK_I(): ARRAY which stores the processes which are in the same line (X direction) than the current process. 
 - I_PROCS: is the number or processes in this line (size of ALRNK_I)
 - LENGTH(1): is the physical size (meters) of a current domain in X direction. Each process receives the Xmax of the left neighbor (that it stores in its Xmin buffer) and sends its Xmax value to it's right neighbor (which does the same thing). We just have to care with the limits and make a cycling condition...(in the code, the xmax value is XEND, the xmin value is XORI)

```
  DO N=1,I_PROCS-1
    DEST=NEIGHBORS(1 , 0, 0)
    SOUR=NEIGHBORS(-1, 0, 0)
    XEND=XORI+LENGTH(1) ! UPDATE ORIGIN

    IF (DEST.EQ.MPI_PROC_NULL) DEST=ALRNK_I(1)

    IF (SOUR.EQ.MPI_PROC_NULL) THEN
      SOUR=ALRNK_I(I_PROCS)
      CALL MPI_SENDRECV(XEND, 1, MPI_REAL8, DEST, TAG,
 &                     DUMMY, 1, MPI_REAL8, SOUR, TAG,
 &                            COMM_IKJ,STATUS, MPIERR)
    ELSE
      CALL MPI_SENDRECV(XEND, 1, MPI_REAL8, DEST, TAG,
 &                      XORI, 1, MPI_REAL8, SOUR, TAG,
 &                            COMM_IKJ,STATUS, MPIERR)
    ENDIF
  ENDDO
```